# Where are Kile settings stored?

Tags: settings, kile

I want to give someone else my settings and preferences for Kile (LaTeX editor). A quick googling would reveal where those settings are strored. Can askubuntu help me?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks a lot! Do you care to write an answer, that I can then accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings of Kile (and probably most other KDE apps and KDE itself) are usually stored in the directory `.kde/share/config`.

To specifically answer your question, I think the settings of Kile are stored in `.kde/share/config/kilerc`.

Comment: And the shortcuts are stored in `~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/katepartui.rc`